# Julia: Why is it necessary to collect the output after reshaping an Array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia, reshape

```
A = collect(reshape(1:16, 4, 4))
4×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  5   9  13
 2  6  10  14
 3  7  11  15
 4  8  12  16
```

How come is it necessary to `collect`? Can't `reshape` automatically output a `4x4 Array{Int64, 2}`? In which cases would I need a `Base.ReshapedArray{Int64,2,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{}}`?

Comment: Why do you need an `Array`? A `ReshapedArray` should be fine for most purposes and can be used instead of an array. `collect` requires an allocation so I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: The thing is I don't understand what's the difference between Array and ReshapedArray. If they can be used interchangeably, why is there a differentiation between the two in the first place

Comment: The `ReshapedArray` is a view with type-level information to make the re-indexing fast. In most algorithms you can use the two interchangably, but there needs to be a difference in types if you want the view to be fast. But you can just write functions that work on `AbstractArray`s through indexing and the like, so it doesn't matter what `AbstractArray` you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key here is that `reshape` generally provides a *view* into the original data structure… it's just changing the way you look at that data into a new shape.  In this case, your original data structure is just the range `1:16`.

Ranges are very compact and efficient array-like objects.  They don't need to store all their elements; instead they just do basic math to compute each element on the fly.  In this manner they can actually be *faster* than the the `Array`-equivalent (like `collect(1:16)`).  In most cases you can use ranges anywhere `Array`s work.  This is a prime reason why you shouldn't specify `arg::Array` or `::Matrix` in a function signature — instead you (and other library authors) should use `::AbstractArray` and `::AbstractMatrix` if you don't need in-memory representations.

There are two major exceptions: Ranges are completely immutable — you cannot assign into or modify any of their elements.  So that's one reason why you may want to `collect` into an `Array`.  Another is if you're calling into a C/Fortran/external library that doesn't support Julia's generic flexibility. In those cases, they're often requiring an in-memory representation like `Array`.

The same is true for `reshape(1:16, 4, 4)`. Similar to how ranges compute their elements on-the-fly, a `ReshapedArray` transforms the indices you pass to it back into the original shape of the original array (`1:16`) in this case, and then it accesses that original array. It does this very efficiently.  In fact, if you peek behind the curtain you can see that it's just storing 4 integers:

```
julia> dump(reshape(1:16, 4, 4))
Base.ReshapedArray{Int64,2,UnitRange{Int64},Tuple{}}
  parent: UnitRange{Int64}
    start: Int64 1
    stop: Int64 16
  dims: Tuple{Int64,Int64}
    1: Int64 4
    2: Int64 4
  mi: Tuple{} ()
```

All it needs to know is the start and the stop of the `UnitRange` parent (1-16), and the dimensions that it gets reshaped to (4x4).  Everything else is done on-demand.  And as you'll note, the size here doesn't matter — `reshape(a:b, y, z)` will always just store 4 integers, regardless of how big `a:b` is.